# Xcode change to app appears in simulator but not on phone

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

I have been creating an app and deploying it to my device perfectly. Today I added some images to the app but only one or two images show up on the device but all work perfectly on the simulator. I have tried clean and uninstalling the app from the device but no success and have no warnings in console, is there anything else I can try or do?

Comment: Have you tried completely clearing the build directory?  I've heard that the clean project command isn't always successful.  Also try changing the filename to see if some kind of cache is holding on.

Comment: Make sure that you're not including duplicate images in your build. You can use the filter at the bottom of the file browser to filter by name and easily verify that the images have not been included twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the filename case. The device is case sensitive. The simulator is not.